# Which is the equivalent command for Oracle wm_concat in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to retrieve the a list of column names in one single string.

Every column name should appear as separated by a comma

**Example :**

```
col1, col2, col3
```

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have such a function. Please note this has been asked multiple times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
Select Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + T2.ColVlaue  // Add a comma (,) before each value
        From MyTable As T2
        Where T2.ID= T1.ID
        For Xml Path(''), type // Select it as XML
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')  // This is done to remove the first character (,) from the result
From MyTable As T1
Group By T1.Id
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @Value = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + ColValue FROM People
SELECT @Value
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit how it works? Xml Path is a keyword?

Comment: @Revious A SELECT query returns results as a rowset. You can optionally retrieve formal results of a SQL query as XML by specifying the FOR XML clause in the query. The FOR XML clause can be used in top-level queries and in sub queries... The PATH mode together with the nested FOR XML query capability provides the flexibility of the EXPLICIT mode in a simpler manner.

Comment: Thanks, and what's the meaning of "Path" and ".value"?

Comment: I had put comment in my answer.please check it

Comment: Nice solution, but I thought the OP was looking for column names, not values.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @DMason: ah, interesting solution.. it would be worth of modifiyng the text of the question.. what is the proposed solution exactly doing?

Answer (score 0):

**In ORACLE you can do this using the `LISTAGG` function:**

```
    SELECT  
LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ', ')
 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) "col names"
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
      where TABLE_NAME='Table names here';
```

*Was i to late ? kkk :)*